# mysql exists data to add an extra decimal field for auto added

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add an extra letter for already exits MySQL columns. for example.

```
short_name
---------------
DAD
DAD
DAD
```

if it comes same name we want to add a dynamic decimal value "%d"

```
short_name
---------------
DAD
DAD1
DAD2
```

So, i need solutions.?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using variables.  If you want to do an update:

```
set @n := '';
set @rn := 0;

update t
    set name = if(@n = name, concat(name, (@rn := @rn + 1)),
                  if(@n := name, if(@rn := 0, name, name), name)
                 )
    order by name;
```

Comment: @ram4587kmr . . . Other than starting at 0, it should be correct.